# How do I fix a corrupted minecraft file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

I can open the minecraft launcher, but after I log in, the game doesn't open. I have tried the solution to go to %appdata% and delete the minecraft. file, but I can't delete the file. When I try to delete it says, "An unexpected error is keeping you from deleting the file." I have Error 0x80070570: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

Comment: to add onto Rajas' answer about SFC, if you have further questions regarding it, the SuperUser StackExchange site can help you better. hope all goes well!

Answer (score 1):

Run SFC in command prompt

See: [This Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e)